# Rewriting url as clean url

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i want to rewrite my url as clean url and replace it with different url
original url
   http://www.sitename.com/movie?name=gold-2018-full-movie

clean url
   http://www.sitename.com/gold-2018-full-movie

my code in .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^movie/([-\w]+)/$ movie.php?name=$1 [L]
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+movie\.php\?name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ movie/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^movie/([^/]+)/?$ movie.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Why "try this"? What's the explanation here?

Comment: thank you it worked , but it also contains some js , css and images file and i also want it to rewrite